# Nested Schemas with Custom Objects in Mongoose for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, casting, mongoose

I'm stuck on trying to use Mongoose for my simple Node.js app. I have created a couple custom objects in my object that basically implement a linked list data structure. Ive been able to save the objects successfully but the problem comes when I try to retrieve the object and call some of the methods that I have defined for it. I tried using Object.create() as a workaround but that did not work. Here is where the code fails:

```
UserObj.findOne( { username : username } ).exec( function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
        res.status(404).json( {success: false, message: "Database error"} );
        return;
    }
    if(user == null) {
        res.status(404).json( {success: false, message: "Username not Registered"} );
        return;
    }
    var sq = Object.create(MusicQueue, user.songQueue); // Not sure if im supposed to pass in MusicQueue or MusicQueue.prototype. Neither work though
    var pl = sq.getPlaylist();
    res.json({
        username : username,
        lastLogin : user.lastLogin,
        playlist : pl
    });
});
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
    var pl = sq.getPlaylist();
                ^
TypeError: Object object has no method 'getPlaylist'
```

I do have that method defined as part of the prototype in the MusicQueue object (`MusicQueue.prototype.getPlaylist = function() {...};`).

Any ideas on how I can get around this? Is there a way to cast user.songQueue from a generic object to a MusicQueue object and be able to call its instance methods?

Comment: have you logged what the value of sq is? sq should be the instantiated object instance of MusicQueue (sq = new MusicQueue)

Comment: @whiteb0x I just logged it to the console and all it printed was an empty object `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Your `User` Schema should be defined like this:

```
userSchema.methods.getPlayList = function () {
  // * your function*, might need a callback if async...
};

var User = mongoose.Model('User', userSchema);
```

You can add a `static` method by using:

```
userSchema.statics.getUsersById = function(cb) {
  // * do something, and call cb when done, assuming it's async
};
```

You shouldn't use `prototype` to add methods. Mongoose will create an instance of the `User` model for result of calling `findOne`, and the `getPlayList` function, if properly defined as shown above, will be available (it was added to the prototype).

You mentioned in your comment a Linked List. You could do that like this:

```
var nodeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    value: String,
    link: { type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Node' }
});

var Node = mongoose.Model('Node', nodeSchema);
```

Comment: @WiredPrarie I tried doing this but I would have to create a schema for a linked list node which has a value and a pointer to another node. In the Node Schema, it would need a property which is of the type of another Node Schema (for the next). This gave me the error:`TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `next``

Comment: You can just use the type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` without using the `ref` if you want. But, it should work as well.

Comment: Im pretty new to Mongoose/Node.js/Javascript in general so what does using `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` with `ref: 'Node'` do? Can you perhaps elaborate more on how I can use this to model my linked list data structure?

Comment: A linked list probably won't work the way you want in MongoDB (as you won't be able to follow a series of nodes without doing individual queries).

Answer (score -1):

I got around my particular situation by just creating `copy(obj)` methods to my objects that will take the objects returned by the `findOne(...)` method and copy the data in it to my objects. I've come up with other problems as a result of this but Im pretty sure they are unrelated to this question.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, and you're unnecessarily copying data around.